# Continuity and a finite borel measure

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, borel-sets, borel-measures

Let $\mu$ be finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. For fixed $r>0$, let $C_x=\{y :|y−x|=r\}$ and define $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\mu[C_x]$. Prove that $f$ is continuous at $x_{0}$ if and only if $\mu[C_{x_{0}}]=0$.

I have been trying this exercise but i just couldn't find the relation between the borel measure and the continuity of $f$.

Comment: As you have it, $f$ has only the variable $x.$ Maybe include the fixed $r$ as the other variable, and restrict that to $r>0$ [so $f$ becomes a function from a *subset* of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to the reals?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I show that $f$ is continuous in $x_0$ iff $\mu(C_{x_0})=0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2111821/how-can-i-show-that-f-is-continuous-in-x-0-iff-muc-x-0-0)